# Ajax Post, XML Interpretation Error: Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I get this error in the browser console

> XML Interpretation Error: Syntax Error
>   Address: ...../src/sendOrder.php
>   Line 1, Column 1:

I have this code.

```
  function sendOrder() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'src/sendOrder.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {

        }
    });
    uploadFile();
  }
```

And sendorder.php starts with this code and send a mail

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
    exit;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: as for good practice, you should drop `session_start()` to a new line - error will change to Line 2 hopefully and there may be something wrong with how your server is handling sessions

Comment: In order to troubleshoot XML we'd need to see the XML.

Comment: There is no xml

Comment: Jay, it is not the same and I have no xml. I is ajax post to php.